# minimax algorithm resulting a recursion error

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, game-development, minimax

I'm trying to implement this turn-based "Fighting game" using a minimax algorithm. However, I ran into some problems. THe code worked the first time running it but after running it the second time It gave an error.

I thought applying alpha-beta pruning would solve the issue but it's still the same.

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.

This is the minimax algorithm that's causing the error

```
def minimax(self, depth, is_maximizing, alpha, beta):
    if depth == 0 or self.is_winning(self.computer) or self.is_winning(self.player) or self.is_draw():
        if self.is_winning(self.computer):
            return self.computer_score - depth
        if self.is_winning(self.player):
            return -self.player_score + depth
        if self.is_draw():
            return 0

    if is_maximizing:
        best_value = float('-inf')
        for move in ["slash", "thrust"]:
            self.attack = move
            value = self.minimax(depth - 1, False, alpha, beta)
            best_value = max(best_value, value)
            alpha = max(alpha, best_value)
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
        return best_value
    else:
        best_value = float('inf')
        for move in ["block", "dodge"]:
            self.defend = move
            value = self.minimax(depth - 1, True, alpha, beta)
            best_value = min(best_value, value)
            beta = min(beta, best_value)
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
        return best_value
```

What am I missing here? Any answer that's helpful is appreciated.

Comment: How did you run the code to get your error?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the main function..

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]. We should be able to **copy and paste** the code, **without changing or adding anything** (i.e., without inputting anything, or knowing what to input), to see the **exact** problem **directly** (i.e. the code in the example should not do things that are irrelevant to causing the problem, except the minimum needed to understand what is going on). For example: can you cause the problem by **writing code that calls `minimax` twice, with specific arguments**? If you can, then **does the first call actually matter** to causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```py
if depth == 0 or self.is_winning(self.computer) or self.is_winning(self.player) or self.is_draw():
    if self.is_winning(self.computer):
        return self.computer_score - depth
    if self.is_winning(self.player):
        return -self.player_score + depth
    if self.is_draw():
        return 0
```

There is no default condition, so it is possible for your minmax function to go to past `depth=0`. You can fix this easily by adding a return at the end.

```py
if depth == 0 or self.is_winning(self.computer) or self.is_winning(self.player) or self.is_draw():
    if self.is_winning(self.computer):
        return self.computer_score - depth
    if self.is_winning(self.player):
        return -self.player_score + depth
    if self.is_draw():
        return 0
    return 0 # Or replace with an evaluation function
```